# select items from a struct array matlab- based on condition

Tags: matlab

I have a struct array named `Lst`. Every struct has the following form:

```
Point (x,y)
Type (1-6)
```

I want get the separate array of points for each type. How can I get it?

```
Lst(Lst.Type==1);
```

won't work since Type is not a field of `Lst` but of `Lst(i)`.

In  addition, is there a way to save the indexes of each item or an alternative way to then combine them again to the original order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`L1 = Lst([Lst.Type]==1);` will give you the subset `L1` of `Lst` where `Type == 1`.

Likewise, you can use `idx1 = find([Lst.Type]==1)` to memorize your indexes.

**EDIT**: the above uses the `[]` operator to aggregate the field elements `Type` of `Lst` into an array. To your comment/question, you could use the exact same operator also to obtain an array of specific field elements `X` of a subset of the structured array, as in

```
X1 = [Lst([Lst.Type]==1).X];
```

Comment: thanks! not sure if to open another question for this or not, but do you know how to get a lst of only X for example, I want a field in teh lst and not the struct of the items in the list- but a list of only inner items.